# Which way is better when i want to filter a list?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I fetch an api to get the data with `react-redux` to show my `list`. If i want to add a filter function which way is better ?

A:

Still use `react-redux` to change `reducer` . May be add a boolean call filter , if it is true then the `reducer` filter the data to re-render my component.

B:

Just use `this.setState` to change my component. If i choose this way i have to save the data to `this.state` when i call the api data first.

I want to know which way is more efficient and easier.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

According to bntzio suggestion:

My filter will be activated by user in my case, if i choose B:

I already have a loading flag for `react-redux` somthing like

`if(this.props.loading) { return <Loading /> }`
, if i use `this.state` that i have to add another loading flag like `this.state.loading` right ?

Will it become more complicated ?

Comment: If the filter is going to happen without any action required from a user, then it's better to filter the data right away with a reducer, and if a user needs to activate the filter, then use `this.setState`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion bntzio !  I have another doubt in my question, take a look please, thank you.

Comment: According to your updated question, you just need to use one loading state to check for that state, why both? Of course, when the fetch is complete, you need to change the loading state to false.

Comment: Thank you very much bntzio.